# Excitation of electrons from $3p$ to $3d$ in sulphur

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, spectroscopy, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

[image]

In my book it is shown that sulphur in its excited state forms 6 covalent bonds with Fluorine to form SF6 but after the electron is excited does it not dexcite from $3d$ back to $3p$ and $3s$ by emitting a photon? Is a photon really even emitted on dexcitation from sub shells like $s,p,d,f$?

Comment: Are you looking at sulphur orbitals in the context of hybridization of orbitals during the formation of a SF6 compound?

Comment: I just want to know if an electron can emit a photon while dexciting to different subshells within the same principal quantum number like is a photon released when electron dexcites from 2p to 2s within the same 2nd shell

Comment: If we neglect selection rules and stick to the qualitative approximation using orbitals, then yes. But spectroscopy and electronic transitions are not properly described with a simple "electrons-jumping-orbitals" model. That explanation is a very crude simplification and can easily lead to a misunderstanding of orbitals and their role once more than a single electron is involved. Transition only occur between orbitals if your system is made of a single electron or completely uncorrelated electrons. Atomic spectroscopy beyond the hydrogen atom is more complicated.

Comment: Perhaps my answer to your other related question may help a bit: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164168/79678.

Answer (score 0):

> In my book it is shown that sulphur in its excited state forms 6
> covalent bonds with Fluorine to form $\text{SF}_6$ but after the
> electron is excited does it not dexcite from $3d$ back to $3p$ and
> $3s$ by emitting a photon?

Your book clearly refers to the $s p^3 d^2$ [**hybridisation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_hybridisation#spxdy_hybridisation) of sulphur, in accordance with **VSEPR theory**.

This hybridisation forms six *equivalent* (**same energy level**) hybrid atomic orbitals on the $\text{S}$ atom.

Each of these forms a molecular orbital (bonding orbital) with the lone $2p$ atomic orbital of six $\text{F}$ atoms forming $\text{SF}_6$, with an octahedral structure. With these former $s p^3 d^2$ electrons now 'caught up' in molecular bonding orbitals ($\sigma$ type) there's no possibility of 'de-excitation'.

Also, please bear in mind what *@Hans Wurst* wrote in the comments.